Sync Files from Salesforce to external drives like Gdirve or Onedrive
I'm developing a managed package and have a requirement to implement functionality that automatically uploads files attached on managed package object at regular intervals on some external drives like Gdrive or Onedrive. After researching, I find the following solution:

I will create a component into our package to obtain external drive credentials and save them in custom metadata.

I will create a batch job that runs periodically. Inside start method, it will obtain an access token and store it in a static class-level variable.

In execute method, the batch job will use this access token to upload files to the external drive.


Is this approach appropriate? What are its implications, and are there alternative approaches I should consider?

"Alternative"... what will you do better than Salesforce's own Files Connect? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aG3m3zP00KQ is a decade old, corny video - but that means by now the feature is stable, battle-tested...

Thanks @eyescream In my scenario I just want to migrate then delete  my file from Salesforce without using any UI component(either using any async process)
